# Simple JavaScript Function Doesn't Work With No Errors

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and my first and simplest function is not working with no errors

Other js codes work fine but not this

Here is the code: I'm expecting it to simply print what i write in the input field

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head></head>

 <body>

<input type="text" id="myid">
<button onclick="myfunc()">click</button>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript.js file:

```
/*global document */

function myfunc() {
    "use strict";
  document.getElementById("myid").value;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Right now it doesn't do anything. You are accessing the value of the input filed but you are not doing anything with it. Hence you see no output/feedback anywhere.

Comment: u need to console.log  the output

Comment: Print where ? if you want print in the console then use => `console.log(  document.getElementById("myid").value)`

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("myid").value` to `console.log(document.getElementById("myid").value)`

Comment: Thank you all guys for your effort, i wish js has something simple as print() or echo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the value of the input field, you can use `console.log()` to print it's contents to the console. Save the value of the input in a variable for example. Then you can log the value of this variable in your browser's console, or use it for another purpose.

```
function myfunc() {
     "use strict";
     var value = document.getElementById("myid").value;
     console.log(value)
}
```

`document.getElementById("myid").value` did only get the input's value. But you didn't do anything with it.

You can also directly log the value without saving it to a variable first, see the example below.

```
function myfunc() {
     "use strict";
     console.log(document.getElementById("myid").value)
}
```

To show the value on the page, you can create a empty placeholder with an ID you can target. Then set the `textContent` of this placeholder to the value of the input. See the example below.

```js
    function myfunc() {
         "use strict";
         var value = document.getElementById("myid").value;
         /* Select the output placeholder */
         var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
         /* Set the input fields value as the text content */
         outputElement.textContent = value;
    }
```

```html
<html>
        <head></head>

        <body>

            <input type="text" id="myid">
            <button onclick="myfunc()">click</button>
            <!-- This is the output placeholder -->
            <p id="output"></p>

            <script src="javascript.js"></script>

       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *do* anything with the value, you just retrieve it and throw it away. Try

```
function myfunc() {
  alert(document.getElementById("myid").value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple case of this function doesn't do anything.

Your code is correct in terms of getting the value of the input field with the id `myid`.

But after that you're not doing anything with it, if you want to see it you do `console.log()` on the value, or you can assign it to a variable to work with it later on `const inputValue = document.getElementById("myid").value;`

The line `document.getElementById("myid").value;` simply just retrieves the value, and doesn't do anything with it, just throws it away, which is why you don't see any errors or feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to be visible in page,
Create a div in HTML and set a id to it. After that in JS get the value in a variable

`var myId=document.getElementById("myid").value;`
and set that in new div id.

`document.getElementById("printId").innerHTML="myId";`